# Is the Cordova Device UUID the same as the Capacitor Device UUID?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

We are migrating from an Ionic Cordova app to an Ionic Capacitor app. While I know that Capacitor still supports Cordova plugins, we try to migrate as much as possible.

Our app relies on the device UUID provided by the Cordova device plugin. Is this the same as the device UUID provided by Capacitor? I tried to compare both repositories, but I am not completely sure if the Android is actually the same (what is the first argument in the method given below)?

## Here is my comparison:

### **iOS Cordova:**

`[[device identifierForVendor] UUIDString]`

Source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/2fc1d3cac0ed37a37de6a6aa18e7955342037a1d/src/ios/CDVDevice.m#L52-L74

### **Android Cordova:**

`Settings.Secure.getString(this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);`

Source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/2fc1d3cac0ed37a37de6a6aa18e7955342037a1d/src/android/Device.java#L111-L114

### **iOS Capacitor:**

`UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString`

Source: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/0bcd833a6503061be45253b21fca9bd75576efc8/device/ios/Plugin/DevicePlugin.swift#L28

### **Android Capacitor:**

`Settings.Secure.getString(this.context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);`

Source: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/0bcd833a6503061be45253b21fca9bd75576efc8/device/android/src/main/java/com/capacitorjs/plugins/device/Device.java#L43-L45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## iOS

Its the same. The only difference in the case of iOS is the way `uuidString` is accessed. The Cordova plugin was written in Objective-C while the Capacitor plugin is Swift. The same value should be returned for both though.

## Android

The Android plugins also seems to be referencing the same value, just in different ways. Both pass a content resolver from the app Activity context as the first parameter to `Settings.Secure.getString()`. The difference between: `this.context.getContentResolver()` and `this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver()` is how Context is accessed (a big [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and) on Android development).

#### Cordova Plugin

From the Cordova plugin [guidelines](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#android-integration),

> getContext() and getActivity() can return the required Context object

#### Capacitor Plugin

If you go through the code of the Capacitor plugin, the [file](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/0bcd833a6503061be45253b21fca9bd75576efc8/device/android/src/main/java/com/capacitorjs/plugins/device/DevicePlugin.java#L17) that is the main entry point calls `getContext()` and directly passed it to the `Device()` [constructor](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/0bcd833a6503061be45253b21fca9bd75576efc8/device/android/src/main/java/com/capacitorjs/plugins/device/Device.java#L20).

In short both refer to the same Activity Context. `this.context` is the same as `this.cordova.getActivity()`

Comment: The Swift/Objective-C comparison is clear, it's the same code. What is the difference of  `this.context.getContentResolver()` vs `this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver()`? I was not able to understand what this value is doing.

Comment: @andreas, take a look at my updated answer.