# java file not imported in my kotlin project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, error-handling

Please I am working with kotlin and when I tried to move from one Activity to another using an intent, i got an error on the java keyword which says "unresolved reference" when i click to see some suggestions they told me to create an Extension property of Kclass.java. I don't really know what is the issue as i have tried so many suggestions but still cant solve it.
Here is the code.

```
class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if(firebaseUser !=null){
            val intent = Intent(this@WelcomeActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ukeme please edit the question and copy paste the logcat/stack trace output which is showing the error.

Comment: Don't Understand Your Question Can you describe it in brief?

Comment: The error is not in the logcat. the error is showing in this "java" keyword "val intent = Intent(this@WelcomeActivity,MainActivity::class.java)" which says unresolved reference and one of the suggestions is to create an extension property of the Kclass <MainActivity>.java

Comment: what i meant is this .java in the "val intent = Intent(this@WelcomeActivity,MainActivity::class.java)" is underlined red with a message that says "unresolved reference" @JayeshDankhara

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild project @Ukeme

Answer (score 1):

You might probably want to move these codes from `onStart()` to `onCreate()`

```
firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    if(firebaseUser !=null){
        val intent = Intent(this@WelcomeActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
```

This is so that the target Activity (`MainActivity`) starts immediately the `WelcomeActivity` has been fully created (not just when it starts) and when the Firebase user's authentication has been verified.

Also, the error might be coming from this snippet.

```
intent = Intent(this@WelcomeActivity,MainActivity::class.java)"
```

Which you say "is underlined red with a message that says "unresolved reference".

What you need to start the `MainActivity` is a [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context), I think that is where the problem is.

So try any of the following.

```
intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

intent = Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity::class.java)
```

If you do not understand what `Context` is all about then check this StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and).

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I have tried it and still not working, I don't know if it's because i updated my kotlin plugin recently that is giving me all these issues because toLowerCase function that i wanted to use is not working