# SqlDelight KMM app where is the generated SQL database located

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I have a KMM app for iOS/Android where I am using `SQLDelight` (1.5.3). I would like to find the generated DB file (maybe .SQLite) and open it to see the content. (maybe using `DB Browser in SQLite`).

I am able to find the file through `Xcode`, but not sure how to do it using Android Studio for the Android app. Where is the file located? What is the format that is generated through the `AndroidSqliteDriver`.

I might have the wrong expectation, how can I visualize what I have in the DB?

Thanks.

Comment: I checked out their repo and it uses Android's `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper` to handle the file ([follow the `name` parameter in `AndroidSqliteDriver.kt`](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/blob/f034a36f43ca74366cf59cf2790b98d33dab71d9/drivers/android-driver/src/main/java/app/cash/sqldelight/driver/android/AndroidSqliteDriver.kt)) - and it gets `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper` from `getApplicationContext()` which is also part of Android's platform lib - so the database files will be saved wherever the default DB location is on Android, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Dai! I found a good explanation of various contexts here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10641257/429763
So the emulator was here: `~/.android/avd/` and then based on the `applicationContext` debug details the files should have been at `/data/user/0/com.myapp/files`.. could not find it there though.. no hidden files either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in `/data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<Your-DB-Name>` on your device. For emulator the easiest way to go to device manager in your Android studio [image: Android Studio screen]