# getApplicationContext(), getBaseContext(), getApplication(), getParent()

Tags: android, android-context

What is the difference between:

1. `getApplicationContext()`
2. `getBasecontext()`
3. `getApplication()`
4. `getParent()`

Can you elaborate with one simple example?

Comment: please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context that define same thing
also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`getApplicationContext()` Application context is associated with the Application and will always be the same throughout the life cycle.

`getBasecontext()` should not be used, just use `Context` instead of it which is associated with the activity and can be destroyed when the activity is destroyed.

Comment: what about getApplication() and getParent()