# Android: why must use getBaseContext() instead of this

Tags: android, this, android-context

`this` often to reference to current context. But, at some case, why we must use `getBaseContext()` instead of `this`. (It means when use `this` will notice error).

Here is my example:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);            
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SELECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //this line
    }
```

At above code, when I  change `getBaseContext()` to `this` will receive error.

Who can explain for me, please.

Comment: Do not use `getBaseContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` unless you know **exactly and specifically why** you are using it. Newcomers to Java should spend time learning Java before getting into Android programming, so you will learn about things like `OuterClass.this` and not be confused when you encounter the need for them.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you give me a good link for this, please. (I'm just know the different of `getBaseContext()` and `getApplicationContext`

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?InnerClass and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html and http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2009/04/07/java-nested-inner-class-this/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974/keyword-for-the-outer-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class

Comment: it will give error if you pass  `this` because you are passing current Activty context but this method require only `Context` object.

Comment: You are getting an error with this because it refers to a Listener object, not Activity.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854265/getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-getapplication-getparent

Answer (score 56, accepted):

1. `getApplicationContext ()` returns the application context of the entire application life cycle,when  application will destroy then it will  destroy also.
2. `this` the context returns the current context of the activity, belong to the activity, the activity is destroyed then it will destroy also.but in your case it will refers to the `Spinner` instance because we are using this within `onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)` method which is from  `Spinner` class and `Spinner` inherit this method  from `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` interface
3. `getBaseContext()` is the method of `ContextWrapper`. And `ContextWrapper` is, "*Proxying implementation of Context that simply delegates all of its calls to another Context. Can be subclassed to modify behavior without changing the original Context.*" (as per javadocs)..

**and in your case :`Spinner` class is not subclass of `Context` or `ContextWrapper` class***

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SELECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

means `getBaseContext()` is method of `ContextWrapper` and `ContextWrapper` is Proxying implementation of `Context` so indirectly we are passing an Context Class Object.

or we can also pass 'Activity.this' because `Activity` class is subclass of `ContextWrapper` class .

if you go with [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) then this method requires a Context class object:
`public static Toast makeText (Context context, int resId, int duration)`

so we are not able to pass an activity or class context means `this` to  `Toast.makeText` which don't have a subclass of either `Context` or `ContextWrapper` class.

Comment: I thought "this" refers to OnItemSelectedListener - not Spinner. As in answer by Sergey Glotov below.

Answer (score 16):

In your example `this` refers to newly created `OnItemSelectedListener` not to any context object. If this code is in activity you can write `YourActivity.this` instead of `getBaseContext()`.

```
OnItemSelectedListener listener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
       // this.equals(listener) == true;

       // getBaseContext() here means YourActivity.this.getBaseContext()
       // getBaseContext() called from outer context object (activity, application, service)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it true when say `each thread has it own context object` ? So, `onItemSelectedListener` is on different thread of UIThread, so we cannot use `this` keyword, right ?

Comment: 1. AFAIK, `onItemSelectedListener` is on UI thread. 2. It is not related to the threads. [`this` is a reference to the current object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html). In `onItemSelected()` method current object is `OnItemSelectedListener`.

Answer (score 9):

If this code is in the Activity `MyActivity`, you could also replace `getBaseContext()` by `MyActivity.this`.

This is because `this` refers to the OnItemSelectedListener instance, not to the Activity.
`getBaseContext()` refers to the Activity context.

Answer (score 5):

`OnItemSelected` method this refers to the new `OnItemSelectedListener` instance that you used.
`getBaseContext` is you outer class.

Comment: same question as I have asked Sergey, Does it true when say each thread has it own context object ? So, onItemSelectedListener is on different thread of UIThread, so we cannot use this keyword, right ? Thanks :)

Comment: AFAIK `this` refer to the instance where you are. If you're in an inner (or anonymous) class, it refers to that inner class. No matter if you're in the thread 1 or 30.

Comment: louiscoquio is right. The thread doesn't have any relation to the context. "this" refers to the instance.

Answer (score 4):

getBaseContext() refers to Activity.this

like we want to showing Toast on click of button, we never user this we use Activty.this. So that our  Toast display till we are on the same activity.
But if we use getApplicationContext() than our Toast will display even we switch the activity.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `this` refers `OnItemSelectedListener` .And its `Interface not Class` .so it's gives you error ,,, Always Use if you are in Activity `YourActivityName.this`

Answer (score 3):

The getBaseContext() Sometimes confuses new comers to android, instead one could also use the ActivityName which is the current activity in which your are working. so ActivityName.this will replace getBaseContext()