# Using "getBaseContext" Or "this" when using Toast to display Messages

Tags: android

I am having button that laid out in Linear Layout on Activity .

when I clicked on it, an message appear on screen using Toast Class

two methods works fine for me

first one is :

```
private void DisplayToast(String msg)
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and the second one is :

```
private void DisplayToast(String msg)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, msg,
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

my question is what is the deference between `getBaseContext()`  and `this`
,and when I should use `getBaseContext()` and when I should use  `this` ??

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605459/android-why-must-use-getbasecontext-instead-of-this

Comment: short answer is you should basically never be using `getBaseContext()` unless you know exactly why you need to use it ;-) Used incorrectly it is prone to memory leaks, and it is rarely ever actually needed you are normally ok with either `YourActivity.this` or `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: getBaseContext() is used in special cases.If you are under Activity always preffer using Activity Context i.e this

Comment: Ok thank you all :), but in the above code why  two methods are working fine for me and didn't get any errors ???

Comment: using `getBaseContext()` will not produce any immediately visible errors. But it is unneeded in this situation and _can_ lead to mean memory leaks so it is best to avoid using it unless you understand exactly when and why its needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity is a Context, so use it directly with `this`.

Keep `getBaseContext` for special cases where your Activity is not reachable directly.