# How to get my activity context?

Tags: android, android-context

I don't really get the idea behind how this whole thing works really, so if I have some class `A` that need the context of a class `B` which extends `Activity`, how do i get that context?

I'm searching for a more efficient way than giving the context as a parameter to class `A` constructor. For example if class `A` is going to have millions of instances then we would end up having millions of redundant pointer to `Context` while we should be able somehow to have just one somewhere and a getter function...

Comment: classA.this is your Activity context.

Comment: But why do you need A context in Class B?

Comment: @Rakesh You get it wrong... he needs the B context in class A (which does not extend Activity). This is something common.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `Application` class(public class in android.application package),that is:

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.
>   You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class
>   to be instantiated for you when the process for your
>   application/package is created.

To use this class do:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public static void setContext(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    ...

}
```

In your manifest:

```
<application
        android:icon="..."
        android:label="..."
        android:name="com.example.yourmainpackagename.App" >
                       class that extends Application ^^^
```

In Activity B:

```
public class B extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sampleactivitylayout);

        App.setContext(this);
                  ...
        }
...
}
```

In class A:

```
Context c = App.getContext();
```

**Note**:

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation,
>   static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular
>   way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register
>   broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a
>   Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when
>   first constructing the singleton.

Comment: Can I ask why does it need to implement OnInitListener ?

Comment: Alternatively, since your app presumably has a main activity (mine is named `MainActivity`), you could put the static `Context` members in that class. (Merely because you've already made that custom class, so no need to make another class, App.) On the other hand, it is arguably clearer to put stuff in `App` that is not really related to `MainActivity`.

Comment: Either way, it is important to ***set the static to null*** when Class B goes away.  Otherwise, that Class B instance, which is an activity that may hold lots of resources, will not be GC'd until your app exits. (If Class B is your ***main activity, and you do want to keep it around until your app exits***, then disregard this comment.)

Comment: Keeping contexts as static can cause memory leaks in Android.

Comment: `OnInitListener` that is decalred in `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`?

Comment: `OnInitListener` is not needed, it was probably forgotten. I removed it

Answer (score 65):

Ok, I will give a small example on how to do what you ask

```
public class ClassB extends Activity
{

 ClassA A1 = new ClassA(this); // for activity context

 ClassA A2 = new ClassA(getApplicationContext());  // for application context. 

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's more better than using an `Application` class.

Answer (score 39):

The best and easy way to get the activity context is putting `.this` after the name of the Activity. For example: If your Activity's name is `SecondActivity`, its context will be `SecondActivity.this`

Comment: I wonder what the difference is between this solution and the more complex accepted solution -- if there is a difference at all.

Comment: @DavidGay getApplicationContext returns the context for the entire application, this is no recommended to use, at least you need to get the application context

Comment: @John Alexander Betts Thank you!
This should be the accepted answer and should get the highest vote.

This is a very simple and straight forward answer that actually answers the OP's question as against complicated, unclear and error-prone hack-like solution that was accepted as answer.

Answer (score 3):

you pass the context to class B in it's constructor, and make sure you pass getApplicationContext() instead of a activityContext()

Comment: applicationContext and activity context are different, they have different lifespans and you should use it accordingly.

Comment: @Gan depends what's the point of Class B at all; somehow i just presume that ApplicationContext will be more useful than activity context. but that's just me :)

Comment: @Shark : The application context is only a partial context and doesn't work for some things in particular UI related operations.

Comment: @Squonk can you name a few? I haven't encountered a case where application context fails and activity context doesn't.

Comment: @Shark : Sorry, I worded that badly. If the requirement is just to have a `Context` then either the application context or an activity context will work. If, however, the class being passed the context is a 'helper' class that might do UI-related work then `ctx.getWindowManager()` (for example) wouldn't be a valid method call if `ctx` was a reference to the application context. In other words, it really depends on *why* the class needs to be passed a 'context' and what it needs it for.

Comment: @Shark you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4128799/328947 where the same discussion is on the same context.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a constructor using parameter Context of class A then you can use this context.

Context c;

A(Context context){
this.c=context
}

From B activity you create a object of class A using this constructor and passing getApplicationContext().

Answer (score 0):

If you need the context of A in B, you need to pass it to B, and you can do that by passing the Activity A as parameter as others suggested. I do not see much the problem of having the many instances of A having their own pointers to B, not sure if that would even be that much of an overhead.

But if that is the problem, a possibility is to keep the pointer to A as a sort of global, avariable of the `Application` class, as @hasanghaforian suggested. In fact, depending on what do you need the context for, you could even use the context of the `Application` instead.

I'd suggest reading [this article](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=78ad4cb95e-Android_Weekly_64&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-78ad4cb95e-328260729) about context to better figure it out what context you need.

Comment: Since this is a year later than the accepted answer, which already shows in detail how to do this, this shouldn't be a separate answer:  The only "new" part is the last sentence, which contains a *useful link*. This would be best as a ***comment*** on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin will be :

```
activity?.applicationContext?.let {
         it//<- you context
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The MainActivity class has those properties you can use:

- applicationContext
- baseContext
- this

See here for differences: [difference and when to use getApplication(), getApplicationContext(), getBaseContext() and someClass.this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347184/difference-and-when-to-use-getapplication-getapplicationcontext-getbasecon)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know who may need this at this point but:
@hasanghaforian is correct, and contrary to what @gezdy says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13994622/11214643), no, using `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` is not a solution, no matter how you look at the problem, it doesn't even make sense...

One could... maybe create a working version that uses the `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` option but it would be unnecessarily complex and slower.

The aim is to:
Proactively retrieve the top most desired Activity.

Now the problem with Hasan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12321393/11214643) and gezdy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13994622/11214643) is that neither acknowledges the fact that, the same way Fragments stack one on top of each other, Activities can ALSO be stacked, so we need a LinkedDeque...

```
public class ActivityRegistry extends Application {
    private final LinkedList<Activity> activities = new LinkedList<>();
    public<A extends Activity> boolean register(A activity) {
        return !contains(activity) && activities.offerLast(activity);
    }
    public void unregister() {
        activities.pollLast();
    }

    public<A extends Activity> A getLastActivity(Class<A> componentTYpe) {
        Activity current = getLastActivity();
        return componentTYpe.isInstance(current) ? componentTYpe.cast(current) : null;
    }

    public<A extends Activity> boolean contains(A activity) {
        return activities.contains(activity);
    }

    public void clear() {
        activities.clear();
    }

    private Activity getLastActivity() {
        return activities.peekLast();
    }
}
```

You must take into consideration that the `register(A activity)` method adds ONLY IF object is NOT PRESENT.

Since BOTH answers are registering Activities during the RESUME phase of the lifecycle, and then unregistering them during the DESTROY.
The Registration - Unregistration cycle is NOT a CLOSED LOOP.

This means that if the app goes to the background and then to the foreground again 2 instances will be added, since the RESUMED phase gets called twice without traversing the DESTROY.
My solution prevents that, but another alternative is to register during the `onCreate()` phase of the Activity..

Now as to the "Memory Leak" issue from the Activity perspective.

There is NO NEED to assign the context to a field, IF the context can be accessed from a method, IN FACT, methods are provided precisely to avoid MemLeaks, since, if there would be NO danger of it leaking, the variable could be easily passed via constructor parameter.

This is Gezdy's code:

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {
    protected MyApp mMyApp; //This field will create a Memory Leak

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMyApp = (MyApp)this.getApplicationContext();
        //If app context can be accessed via method, we dont need to assign it to a field.
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMyApp.setCurrentActivity(this);
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        clearReferences();
        super.onPause();
    }
    protected void onDestroy() {        
        clearReferences();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void clearReferences(){
        Activity currActivity = mMyApp.getCurrentActivity();
        if (this.equals(currActivity))
            mMyApp.setCurrentActivity(null);
    }
}
```

Instead do this:

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((ActivityRegistry)getApplicationContext()).register(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {        
        ((ActivityRegistry)getApplicationContext()).unregister();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Now the Activity can be retrieved like this:

```
    MyActivity activity = ((ActivityRegistry)getApplicationContext()).getLastActivity(MyActivity.class);
//If activity returns null, it means the last Activity was NOT of type MyActivity.class.
//If you pass Activity.class instead, it will always get you the last Activity.
//And the you must FORCE CAST into what you believe it to be the type.
```

Where `MyActivity extends MyBaseActivity`