# android - null pointer exception when try get view from another layout

Tags: android, view

I am in activity MainActivity which use the layout main2:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main2);
```

Now I want to get view "btnDisplay " from  another layout called " row_in_list_test" .

I did :

```
LinearLayout row_in_list_tests = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.row_in_list_tests);

btnDisplay = (Button) row_in_list_tests.findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay); //null pointer exception

btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ..
```

but in runTime i get "null pointer exception".

When I get btnDisplay in this way :

```
btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
```

it is work good but then I get "null pointer exception" in the next line :

```
btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { .. /null pointer exception
```

What is the way to do it?
(I don't need to inflate  " row_in_list_test" , it is just a layout for ArrayAdapter0

Comment: You're trying to get a view that does not exist. What do you want to achieve, really?

Comment: row_in_list_test is a linearlayout, not a View that's why you get the null pointer. Moreover you can only access elements of a view that has been inflated.

Comment: Are you making a custom list or what? Why do you need to access a button of other layout?

Comment: I just want to define onClickListener on the button (the button is in xml file of layout I use as custom arrayAdapter)

Answer (score 0):

You only can get the views of a layout defined in: setContentView().

So there must be an other activity using this method to create a context:

> ```
>  setContentView(R.layout.row_in_list_tests);
> ```

Now you can get access to this layout with the context of the other activity:

> ```
>  btnDisplay = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
> ```

How to get the context of other activities is an other problem, which is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320857/how-to-get-my-activity-context).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bthDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });
```