# How to get Android Activity context in appium project?

Tags: android, appium, android-context

I want to get Current android activity context in `appium` test project. There are methods to get current activity name but how to get its context (`android.content.Context`)?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12321393/2811956

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        for (String contextName : contextNames) {
            System.out.println(contextNames);
}
```

This will give you all the context names.

Comment: you are right this will give me the context name(string) but I want a context object(android context object that is android.content.Context)