# the method getactivity() is undefined for the type Use In activity_main for User Database

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a user database on my activity_main page so that when users sign into the app, it will then lead them to the next major page. Here is the ActivityMain.java file currently:

```
         package com.example.awesomefilebuilder;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
    public class MainActivity extends Base_Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.awesomefilebuilder.MESSAGE";
    public final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public final String edit_message ="Username";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "comments_table";
    public static final String C_ID = "_id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String COMMENT = "comment";
    public static final String EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String TIME = "time";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;

    View view;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DbHelper dbhelper;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        DbHelper dbhelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        view = inflater.inflate(R. layout.activity_main, container,false);


            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();


        cv.put(DbHelper.NAME, NAME);
        cv.put(DbHelper.COMMENT, COMMENT);
        cv.put(DbHelper.EMAIL, EMAIL);
        cv.put(DbHelper.PASSWORD, PASSWORD);
        db.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);


    Button query = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.query);
    query.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            String [] columns = {DbHelper.NAME, DbHelper.COMMENT, DbHelper.EMAIL};

            Cursor cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

                while(cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.NAME));
                    String comment = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COMMENT));
                    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.PASSWORD));
                    String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.EMAIL));

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name = "+ name +"/nComment= "+ comment,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                cursor.close();




        }

    });
        return view;


    }


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate" );

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();  // Always call the superclass

    // Stop method tracing that the activity started during onCreate()
    android.os.Debug.stopMethodTracing();
}


/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomePageMain.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.createpicture);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
    Log.i(TAG, "sendMessage" );
    }

}
```

I read around on the site and understand that the getActivity() option should only be used on fragments, however I don't want to use a fragment for a simple user login screen. What can I do to either replace the getActivity() option, or just in general to fix the error? Also, I do not want to have to connect to a seperate database even though I have one readily avalible for use when I can just create the database in my application, which I have done. If anyone needs to see any extra pages of coding that will make this easier to solve please let me know.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: can you try with `this` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you cannot use getActivity() in Activity class because this method is of Fragment class. in your case you can do something like :**

```
DbHelper dbhelper = new DbHelper(this);
```

or

```
DbHelper dbhelper = new DbHelper(MainActivity.this);
```

or

```
DbHelper dbhelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

**NOTE:** *Code you pasted here is syntactically wrong because onCreateView() is not a method of Activity class , it is a method of Fragment class. You should write your code in onCreate() method which you written in onCreateView() method.**`strong text`***

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Here's very good answer regarding [getApplication(), getApplicationContext(), getBaseContext() and someClass.this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347184/difference-and-when-to-use-getapplication-getapplicationcontext-getbasecon/10347346#10347346)

```
DbHelper dbhelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
```