# Android - Actionbar tab + dialog

Tags: android, tabs, dialog

I have app that works perfectly without this part of code:

```
if(tab.getPosition() == 4)
    {
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
         builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
         builder.setMessage("This is Example of Alert Dialog with three Buttons");
         builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ok is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             }
         });
         builder.show();
    }
```

that is inside the

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
```

I have 5 tabs + 1 that should just show dialog... When I click this tab my app crushes with error:

```
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:797)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:288)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at com.iecom.eresitev.WeekActivity.onTabSelected(WeekActivity.java:411)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:603)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1145)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:658)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
11-22 14:32:00.818: E/AndroidRuntime(17853):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: instead of using `getApplicationContext` kindly try to use `this` or `WeekActivity.this`

Comment: from where are you calling this? if you are using a fragment make sure you are calling this after onCreateView, a good place to call it will be onActivityCreated, also you can replace "Ok" with android.R.string.ok

Comment: @MehulJoisar Wow.. thanks for that ... should getApplicationContext or getBaseContext work? If you are so kind and put a little explanation about all 3 methods in an answer I will definitely accept and + 1 you answer! Thanks!

Comment: I know that I should put resource in ... it is not actual text, just a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using getApplicationContext kindly try to use `this` or `WeekActivity.this`

**Explaination:**

you need to give reference of current context for `Activity` not for `Application`.

**Reference:**

[difference between activity context and application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347184/difference-and-when-to-use-getapplication-getapplicationcontext-getbasecon)