# Toast not appearing on Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: android, toast

I have an application that uses Toast and I have tested it on a Samsung Galaxy II using Android 4.3 and it works fine.

I have recently gotten a Nexus 5 running Android 4.4 KitKat and when I try to load the Toast it doesn't appear.

Has Toast been removed or the syntax altered in KitKat?

This is the code I'm using to make and call the Toast:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)
{
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {

    case R.id.action_settings:
        Log.e("TOAST","This was called");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is my Toast message!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have Debugged the code and stepped through this part line by line so it is definitely being called, but nothing happens.

Comment: Does the `getBaseContext()` work as the first argument ?

Comment: Regarding `Context`, perhaps [this answer on other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10347346/2821954) may help you.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context

Comment: Have you tried `getApplication()`?

Comment: getBaseContext() and getApplication() don't work. The toast is still hidden.

Comment: Code looks good (modulo the typo in `MainActivty`) and works on my kitkat. The debugger can lie to you - add e.g. logging to the switch-case to confirm the case is taken.

Comment: I added logging and it was logged every time it should have. I tried it on a 4.4 emulator and it worked fine. I'm starting to wonder is it do with the Nexus 5 device rather than KitKat

Comment: Dude, take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507416/toasts-stopped-working-in-4-4-2

maybe is the same to you too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: any specific reason why should he use Activity.this instead of getApplicationContext()?

Comment: @PareshMayani: Here just a `context`(reference) of `current activity` is required rather than context of `application`

Comment: @MehulJoisar Both ApplicationContext as well as ActivityContext can be used with Toast, since a Toast is not tied to a window and can be shown from everywhere in your app. See [Toast.makeText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29)

Comment: Using this or YourActivity.this makes no difference. It still doesn't appear but it works fine on an the device running Android 4.3

Comment: @PriestVallon: It is strange !! Can you post the code from where u r firing `toast` ?

Comment: @PriestVallon: Look at Anil's answer. I've updated it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `YourActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

**EDIT :**

Code seems valid.the issue is either `nexus` or `kitkat`.

- give a try by rebooting your cell.
- give a try by firing the toast from `onResume()`. just to make sure that it is working fine from `UI thread`.

Comment: any specific reason why should he use Activity.this instead of getApplicationContext()?

Comment: @PareshMayani Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context

Comment: Using this or YourActivity.this makes no difference. It still doesn't appear but it works fine on an the device running Android 4.3

Comment: @MehulJoisar Tried both and neither fixed it. Would it matter that the MainActivity has fragments displaying inside of it?

Comment: @PriestVallon: No,it should not matter.