# Toasts stopped working in 4.4.2

Tags: android, toast, android-4.4-kitkat

In my app Toasts have worked fine until my RazrM phone was upgraded to 4.4.2. then they stopped. I have tried specifically runInUiThread and moving the call to initiate from different places in the code including in onCreate(). The issue [20373751] ([Toast not appearing on Android 4.4 KitKat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373751/toast-not-appearing-on-android-4-4-kitkat)) proposes rebooting or specifically running on the UI thread. Neither makes a difference.

That issue also questions if there is a bug in Nexus or KitKat. I have the Toasts running fine in 4.0.4 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab. So I am thinking the problem is in 4.4. Has anyone found a workaround? (BTW I am compiling to a target of Version 9, so it is not an issue with the compile level.But I am using the infamous 23.0.2 SDK.) Can anyone prove that Toasts work under 4.4.2 while using SDK 23.0.2?

Comment: Amazing! I am the only person who has discovered their Toasts aren't working.

Comment: Found the answer in [21098062]. The ShowNotifications box had become unchecked during testing of my app. Never knew that would turn off Toasts for the app!

Comment: Thanks @marcin_j for your answer. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [21098062] @marcin_j said:

> On Jelly Bean 4.1 or higher,you can disable apps notifications from device settings. Just open notification bar, long tap on any of notifications and click App Info, you should see “Show notifications”. Unchecking this option should disable toasts in your app.
>
> If your app does not show any notifications, then you should be able to reach App Info screen from applications manager.
>
> Maybe this is the cause of you missing toasts

---

This was absolutely correct. My 4.0.4 device was not affected but my 4.4.2 device had had Show notifications unchecked.