# Difference between base context, application context and activity context

Tags: android

what is the actual difference between getBaseContext(),getApplicationContext() and activity context which we get by ActivityName.this ?

Comment: It's better to do some quick search before make a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347184/difference-and-when-to-use-getapplication-getapplicationcontext-getbasecon