# Context Methods in Android

Tags: android

Hello I am noob in android. I see that in android you can get context using different method. I could not understand the difference between them and when to use what .

Methods : `getApplicationContext()`, `getContext()`, `getBaseContext()`, this (Activity)

Comment: Did you already read the documentation? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()

Comment: Yes I have already wrote in the question **I could not understand the difference between them**

Comment: But you never told us what definitions you were basing your understanding off. It was a valid inquiry..

Comment: To sum it up: It's whole application lifetime vs. activity lifetime

Comment: @donfuxx so getContext(), getBaseContext(), this (Activity) does same - activity lifetime ??

Comment: take a look at the answers of this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10347346/2399024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An 'Application context' is associated with the Application and will always be the same throughout the life cycle of your app (getApplicationContext())

The 'Activity context' is associated with the activity and could possibly be destroyed many times as the activity is destroyed during screen orientation changes and such.(getContext())

Generally don't use getBaseContext(), rather use one of the previous ones as needed.

You might want to use the Application Context (Activity.getApplicationContext()) rather than using the Activity context (this). This is because 'this' needs to be called from within an Activity. (Activity extends Context )

Comment: Generally don't use getBaseContext(), rather use one of the previous ones as needed. Why ??

Comment: getBaseContext() is the method of ContextWrapper

Comment: so what ContextWrapper do if I use getBaseContext ??

Comment: If you need access to a Context from within another context, you use a ContextWrapper. The Context referred to from that ContextWrapper is accessed with the getBaseContext()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext%28%29

Comment: What mean of context from within another context and what this is use for ? You gave nice answer yet I will surely accept your answer

Comment: It could be used for such elements as inflating a view from within a context or for an Async class. However the use of getApplicationContext() is better as it is more explicit