# In login activity, intent is not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In this activity when both password and username are correct then I have shown a toast and an intent to move to next screen after login, but only toast works, intent is not working?

```
btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // get The User name and Password
        String userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
        String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

        // check if the Stored password matches with Password entered by
        // user
        if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewFolders.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

After login it is not moving to `ViewFolders.class`

Comment: try my answer below, and let me know if its working or not.

Comment: dialog.dismiss();, What's use of this line?

Comment: Check your Manifest! May be you did forgot define your ViewFolders activity.

Comment: have you get the any error?

Comment: Is this button btnSignIn in a dialog??

Comment: Yeah this button is in a dialog

Comment: yes i forgot to add Viefolders activity in menifest .. but i didn't got any error prakash

Comment: If Error was not there then there should be Exception fired for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,ViewFolders.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Instead of:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewFolders.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Beside this hope `ViewFolders` activity is added to manifest already

Comment: yes i forgot to add activity in menifest .. oops .. thnku so muchh for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(YOUR ACTIVITY.this,ViewFolders.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ViewFolders.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

and an explanation here
[difference and when to use getApplication(), getApplicationContext(), getBaseContext() and someClass.this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347184/difference-and-when-to-use-getapplication-getapplicationcontext-getbasecon)