# Android Toast context

Tags: android, toast

I want to know the difference between the two contexts in the two Toasts below , when to use this & when to use getActicity ?

```
   Toast.makeText(getActivity() , "Text" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   Toast.makeText(this , "Text" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347184/difference-and-when-to-use-getapplication-getapplicationcontext-getbasecon

Comment: `getActivity()` is used when you are out of the context (i.e.: in a Fragment), where `this` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you say are trying to access it from a `Fragment`, use `getActivity()` else if you are in `Activity` itself, use `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your `Context` with `this` or `getApplicationContext()` with Activities.

```
getActivity()
```

is used with Android Fragments

Answer (score 1):

`this` is actually a pointer that refers to the current class that you are in. `this` can refer to anything like `Activity`, `Fragment`, `View`, etc.A reference of the current object is passed while `this` is used.

`getActivity()` is available only in the `Fragment` class and any other class extending `Fragment` and this method returns an object of the type `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

To create a `Toast` you need a `Context` object.

If you are in an `Activity` class or another class that extends the `Context` class you can use `this` (because the `Activity` is itself a `Context` child )

If you are for example in a `Fragment` class, that doesn't extends `Context`, you should use `getActivity()` to get a `Context` reference.

Here the docs about the `Context` class where you find all the classes that extends it : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html