# How many 'context' we can use at a time simultaneously in different tasks?

Tags: android

In Android programming, How many `context` we can use at a time in different 
    simultaneously executed **Threads** Or **Asynchronous** tasks ?

**Different invoking methods by which you can get context**

1. `getApplicationContext()`,
2. `getContext()`,
3. `getBaseContext()`
4. or `this` (when in the activity class).

**Also check this :**

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

If I am running many **Threads** at a same time so is it Ok to pass `getApplicationContext()` in all of them or Some issue will occurs ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)

Comment: I m asking is there any limit of using these methods at same time ???

Comment: what is your problem actually? you dont know which one to use in your particular use case?

Comment: If i am running many threads at a same time so is it ok to pass getApplicationContext() in all of them

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context) or [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass `getApplicationContext()` any number of time (Background Tasks ) you want,  `getApplicationContext()` simply returns `context` of the application.

Answer (score 0):

you can find many of answers about difference between **Context** uses, **[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347184/difference-and-when-to-use-getapplication-getapplicationcontext-getbasecon)**

every `context` method have some limit to use it.

If you want to use a only **One method or only one way** to initialise some method calling in entire `Activity`.

Then declare `Context` as **Globally** as below, it have no limit to use in `Activity`.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Activity thisActivity;  //Activity object instance

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        thisActivity = this;    // Initialise with this(Context)

           //Or thisActivity = MainActivity.this;
    }
}
```

use `thisActivity` in place of `Context`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass `getApplicationContext()` any number of time you want,  `getApplicationContext()` simply returns `context` of the application.