# Getting an error while passing string using intent

Tags: android

This is my main activity and im passing a string strname

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),newpage.class);
            i.putExtra("firstname", strname);
            startActivity(i);
```

this is the new page where it will show this activity

```
TextView uname1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        uname1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("firstname"));
```

my application closes when i press submit..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: on which line you have the exception?

Comment: When are you initializing that TextView, and where and what is the NPE?

Comment: when i click submit on toasts its showing me all the values i have entered and then the app crashes

Comment: Please share full code with your activity names and error log

Comment: sorry it was problem in the if else ive fixed it

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException happens when you attempt to invoke a method in a null reference. For example `getIntent().getExtras()` in case getIntent() is null --> `null.getExtras()`, this will invoke a NPE.

Check if the intent is non-null before using it to avoid NullPointerException.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String firstName = "";
if (intent != null) {
    firstName = intent.getStringExtra("firstname");
}
uname1.setText(firstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer of this post:
[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

And try not to use `ApplicationContext`, but instead use `BaseContext`
(see: [difference and when to use getApplication(), getApplicationContext(), getBaseContext() and someClass.this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347184/difference-and-when-to-use-getapplication-getapplicationcontext-getbasecon))

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException happens when you attempt to invoke a method in a null reference.

getString like as

```
TextView uname1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
if (intent.getStringExtra("firstname")!=null) {
uname1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtras("firstname"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Activity1:

`Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
 b.putString("firstname", strname);
 myIntent.putExtras(b);`

`startActivity(myIntent);`

Activity2:

`Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
 String value = b.getString("key");
 uname1.setText(value);`