# Passing context into getColor, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-context

I've been trying to set up buttons and other items with custom colours. I'm new to java, and I've been trying to learn how to use context properly. I have done some research, and I am still unable to find a solution.

The android monitor error is a null pointer exception, and this is the line of code it has a problem with.

```
int buttonBackground = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.buttonBackgrounds);
```

I declared this variable within my class, and then further down in a method, I wrote this:

```
percussionButton.setBackgroundColor(buttonBackground);
instrumentButton.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```

I thought that these two might be conflicting, but that's about all I can think off.

I apologise if this has been answered before, I haven't been able to garner an answer from anything I have found so far.

things I've tried before:

```
int buttonBackground = ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.buttonBackgrounds);

int buttonBackground = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.buttonBackgrounds);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read answers for understanding the difference between context getter methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854265/getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-getapplication-getparent).
Maybe that causes the exception, you call `getBaseContext()`, when it returns `null`, hence the null pointer exception.
When want to use the context of an activity (inside the activity class), you can pass `this` (or `YourActivityClass.this`, where YourActivityClass consistently is the name of your activity) as the `Context` argument. So the line with the exception should be something like this:

```
int buttonBackground = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.buttonBackgrounds);
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that at it still has the same error. Thanks for the link, I'll try reading that to learn more.

Comment: Wait, I've just read your question again, and noticed something: if you want to use the value of `buttonBackground` variable, you should set its value from the `onCreate` method of your activity, when the activity (with its stuff, context, etc) is set up.

Comment: Wonderful! it works now, thank you. I hadn't realized it was necessary to have it within the onCreate method.

Comment: It can be called from other methods too, but just if the activity is created (on, or after `onCreate`)