# Android: Cannot Start New Activity Using Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to launch a new activity when a button is pressed but nothing happens and I get no errors. Here is my code:

Main activity

```
public class CSLearn_Python_AppActivity extends Activity {


String tag = "Events";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    //get content from main.xml
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){



//              Intent intent = new Intent("com.Main.Verification");   
//              startActivity(intent);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Verification.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });



 }
```

The new activity

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Verification extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verification);

}

}
```

Verification XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:baselineAligned="true" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:text="@string/Verification" android:id="@+id/Verrification" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/password" android:inputType="textPassword" android:layout_width="112dp">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <Button android:text="@string/LoginBtn" android:id="@+id/loginBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

I added this to the android manifesto

```
<activity android:name=".Verification"
              android:label="Verification">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.Main.VERIFICATION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be really appreciated.

Comment: long live the android manifesto!

Answer (score 5):

Try the code below and register your activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CSLearn_Python_AppActivity.this, Verification.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is CSLearn_Python_AppActivity in the same package than Verification.

May be you can try in the Manifest with:

```
<activity android:name="yourpackage.Verification"
                  android:label="@string/verification" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `intent-filter` in your Verification activity is not necessary.

Comment: Manifest now simply reads <activity android:name=".Verification" android:label="Verification"></activity> but still no luck. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in the getBaseContext(). Use getApplicationContext() instead (the activity's context is also an option but would cause a leak). I havent quite been able to wrap my head around the base context, but it seems to be some sort of proxy doing more or less nothing in its raw implementation.

A more through explanation of the different contexts is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context).

Comment: Thanks for the advice and link. I have tried getApplicationContext() but still nothing! Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Is there no output in logcat either?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change it like this:

```
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Verification.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I made your changes but still nothing happens when I press the button. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the intent filter, and everything in between, from your manifest

do you have all your imports?
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

Comment: Manifest not simply reads <activity android:name=".Verification" android:label="Verification"></activity> but still no luck. Thanks though.

Comment: now try this maybe?
Intent intent=new Intent(CSLearn_Python_AppActivity.this, Verification.class); 
    startActivity(intent);

Comment: also it looks like you have to implements OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CSLearn_Python_AppActivity.this, Verification.class);
startActivity(myIntent);

In your Android manifest file, 

<activity android:name=".Verification" android:label="Verification"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You include the other activity in Manifest file:

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(First.this, Second.class);intent.putExtra("userData",registeredUsersData);startActivity(intent);
```