# Why can't I use getBaseContext() here?

Tags: android, android-context

I want to try getting some value from my Setting using the following code:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.content.*;
public class TCPdumpHandler {

    public void getPreference() {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        Boolean checkboxPreference = prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true);
    }
}
```

But the error is : `The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the type TCPdumpHandler`

Can you tell me the reason why?

Comment: [You shouldn't use `getBaseContext()` at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context) if you don't know why you need exactly that context *(given that this is a beginner question, you probably don't know)*. Rather stick with the activity context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `TCPdumphandler` does not extend from Activity. `getBaseContext()` is a method of that class (technically, of the ContextWrapper class). You need to pass the context to the constructor of `TCPdumphandler`.

Answer (score 0):

The getContext() methods can be called only from classes that extends Activities and Services (and, but I'm not sure, Application). To use context in other classes you should pass a context as a parameter.