# Use of Context to start another Activity

Tags: android, android-context

To start an Activity you need an Intent, like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, class)
```

So to fill in the context parameter, a couple of options are available:

- Use `MyActivity.this` or just `this`
- Use `getApplicationContext()`
- Use `getBaseContext()`

And I'm sure there are one or two more options.
These options all appear in some sort of tutorial, one uses the first, the next uses the third option.

So which one should I use? Does it even matter? Is it different for different cases?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes its different for different cases,

It depends on the scope. Suppose if you are creating a method in a global class that `extends` `Application` to create a `Toast` that is used in every class of your `Application` you can use `getApplicationContext()` to create it.

If you want to create a view that is restricted to that particular Activity you can use `Activity.this`

Also if you want to create an AlertDialog in some inner class say `AsyncTask`, then you have to use `Activity.this`, because the `AlertDialog` is to be linked to `Activity` itself.

Also don't use `getBaseContext()` just use the `Context` that you are having. For getting further information for the same you can see [`this Answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context).

So, the answer to the real question is better to use `Activity.this` to start a new `Activity`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Current_Activity.this, Calling.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 4):

They are different for sure. These are different contexts, and should be used with the least possible scope(context).

For example if we can use Activity's Context instead of ApplicationContext, one should use the activity context, same applies to application context, and base context.

Comment: It is true, but not for `getBaseContext`. `getBaseContext` is a method of `ContextWrapper` class. Developer can't definetely know which context is wrapped with it.

Comment: This makes sense but I'm curious about the "why" of this maxim. And is there a functional difference between starting an activity from another activity or application context?

Answer (score -2):

You do it like this....

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i guess OP knows that SmartLemon :)

Comment: Please read the whole question before answering, not just the first few (?) words :)

Comment: I did read the whole thing, the question was answered, you use Activity.this as shown above.

Comment: "So which one should I use? Does it even matter? Is it different for different cases?"