# How do I find out whether the Context object is being Leaked from one activity to another?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I want to figure out whether the Context object of one activity is being leaked to another activity. Does the following code leak the context of one activity to another?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Demo.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: [Check this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227835/use-of-context-to-start-another-activity/9227958#9227958)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that doesn't "leak" your context. In general, to avoid leaking an Activity context, here's a few tips to follow:

- Never hold a static reference to a `Context`
- Do not pass `View`s between `Activity`s
- Whenever you don't need a `Context` with an `Activity` reference, use the application's `Context` (`context.getApplicationContext()`).
- Use `WeakReference` when holding onto a `Context` while running some background operation (or whenever feasible really)

Comment: I have a question about bullet point 3 - why not always use an Application Context do avoid doubt?

Comment: @barry There are some things that should be tied to the lifecycle of an `Activity`, such as registering a `BroadcastReceiver` or starting a new `Activity`. The later requires an `Activity` `Context` so the new `Activity` has a task to start in (Otherwise you'd need to use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag).

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum, use the Memory Analysis Tool (MAT) for eclipse to inspect a heap dump.