# How can I start another activity after successful facebook login?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to facebook login. I have successfully had my users be able to signup with facebook and get some information from their profile. However I am not able to get the next activity started. How would I be able to get the next activity started. Here is my code:

```
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    final Context context = this;
 //   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 //   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    final SharedPreferences user_data = getSharedPreferences("USER_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

   // session.checkLogin();

    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
            "public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                            // Application code
                            try {

                                editor.putString(user_email, object.getString("email"));
                                editor.putString(user_name, object.getString("name"));
                                editor.putString(user_dob, object.getString("birthday"));
                                editor.putString(user_phone, object.getString("phone"));
                                editor.apply();


                                Intent activity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PhoneActivity.class);
                                startActivity(activity);
                                finish();
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            // String birthday = object.getString("birthday"); // 01/31/1980 format

                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sign up Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sign up Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with LoginActivity.this context instead of getBaseContext()? Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227835/use-of-context-to-start-another-activity

Comment: tried it, not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

place your intent outside try catch block

```
                       try {

                            editor.putString(user_email, object.getString("email"));
                            editor.putString(user_name, object.getString("name"));
                            editor.putString(user_dob, object.getString("birthday"));
                            editor.putString(user_phone, object.getString("phone"));
                            editor.apply();



                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                          //**********over here**************
                            Intent activity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PhoneActivity.class);
                            startActivity(activity);
                            finish();
```

Comment: is the response going to success?

Comment: yes, I am able to get the user details and display them on the screen(here am saving in the shared pref). Which means it's success. But it does not start the next activity.

Comment: Intent activity = new Intent(ActivityName.this, PhoneActivity.class);

Comment: the above code instead of Intent activity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PhoneActivity.class);

Comment: try after commenting overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);

Comment: no success, could not get it to work, changed getBAseContext to StartActivity.this