# start activity quick but back to desktop

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a quick click button to start activity by intent in my android application, it succeed to target activity ,but back to the desktop, I can not understand.
please guide me to resolve this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ActivityDetailActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyG29.gif)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSuKT.png)

Comment: Do edit the question with both the Activity's complete code? And does the app crash?

Comment: This may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227835/use-of-context-to-start-another-activity

Comment: start intent and then activity finish in onresume().

Comment: Please post the exception and stacktrace from your logcat

Comment: please look the image description and guide me,thanks for your help.

Comment: it's done after remove  <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> in the activity theme .

Answer (score 1):

You need to call intent like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityDetailActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```