# Activity not starting from a countdown timer

Tags: android

I have a **CountDownTimer** that looks like this:

```
clock = new CountDownTimer(seconds, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
              timer.setText(String.format(Locale.GERMAN, FORMAT,  
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
              timer.setText("00");
              end();
            }
        }.start();
```

And a method:

```
private void end() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), End.class);

  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
}
```

But the new activity does not start when the timer runs out, why is this?

Comment: You can use `new Handler().postDelay()` for starting activty instead of `onFinish()`

Comment: Is it going to onFinish() method ?

Comment: It is not going `onFinish()`

Comment: what are you doing in the End Activity? Doas your current Activity close?

Comment: dont use application context.
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivty.this, End.class);

Comment: It is going to the onFinish() method because the text is set to "00" for the timer. The End activity right now is just a text box with some words in it, but that activity is not popping up. The current activity keeps running.

Comment: @user8115948 Anything in logs?

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel why shouldn't I use application context?

Comment: Nothing in logs

Comment: see this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227835/use-of-context-to-start-another-activity

Comment: @user8115948 I have tried your code its working. I suspect it may be crashed but not closing the initial activity? Can you double check the logs once the timer runs out? and post here

Comment: Your value for 'seconds' is not too high, right? because your code works fine.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. It works now because I hadn't called the end() method in another place where I was creating the timer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this with your counter

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), End.class));
                finish();
            }
        }, 1000);
```