# Android - Show Dialog from static class

Tags: java, android

I have a simple class that I want to use to show a Dialog message:

```
public class Utils {

    static void ShowMessage(Context c, String DialogTitle, String MessageToDisplay, int LayoutResourceID, int ImageResourceID ){

        //Create new dialog.
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(c);

        //Set the view to an existing xml layout.
        dialog.setContentView(LayoutResourceID);
        dialog.setTitle(DialogTitle);

        //Set textbox text and icon for dialog.
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(MessageToDisplay);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(ImageResourceID);

        //Show the dialog window.
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

And I am trying to call it from my activity, within an OnClickListener event of a button, like so:

```
private OnClickListener btnSubmitIssueClick = new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){
        //Check for valid Summary & Description.
        if(mSummaryEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            Utils.ShowMessage(getBaseContext(), "Submit Issue Error", getBaseContext().getString(R.string.ERROR_SummaryRequired),
                    R.layout.modal_dialog, R.drawable.warning);
            return;
        }else if(mDescriptionEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            Utils.ShowMessage(getBaseContext(), "Submit Issue Error", getBaseContext().getString(R.string.ERROR_DescriptionRequired),
                    R.layout.modal_dialog, R.drawable.warning);
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
03-07 16:56:00.290: W/WindowManager(169): Attempted to add window with non-application token WindowToken{4162e780 token=null}.  Aborting.
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in the base context as the context that is used to create the dialog. This needs to be the context for the activity that is hosting the dialog. The activity itself is actually the context object so you can just pass in a reference to the activity.

The following SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context) gives a more complete explanation.

Comment: Thanks for that link...I always had a difficult time distinguishing between the types of "getContext" methods.