# How to manage media player into a piano keyboard in Android ?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, media-player

I'm trying to make a small piano keyboard but am finding some problems in the management of the media player and the touch of button. 
This is the code I've written so far:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class KeyboardPianoActivity extends Activity {

Button dooT,reT,miT,faT,solT,laT,siT,doodT,redT,fadT,soldT,ladT,doo1T,re1T,mi1T,fa1T,sol1T,la1T,si1T,doo1dT,re1dT,fa1dT,sol1dT,la1dT,doo2T;

MediaPlayer m1; 
MediaPlayer m2;
MediaPlayer m3;
MediaPlayer m4;
MediaPlayer m5; 
MediaPlayer m6; 
MediaPlayer m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

dooT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
reT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
miT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
faT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
solT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
laT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
siT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);


m1 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.do1);
m2 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.re);
m3 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.mi);
m4 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.fa);
m5 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.sol);
m6 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.la);
m7 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.si);



dooT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View arg0) {

m1.start();
}
});

reT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View arg0) {

m2.start();
}
});

miT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View arg0) {

m3.start();
}
});

faT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View arg0) {

m4.start();
}
});

solT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View arg0) {

m5.start();
}
}); 
}
}
```

This is the LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29177): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(29177): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(29177): at      it.bisemanuDEV.piano.KeyboardPianoActivity$1.onClick(KeyboardPianoActivity.java:71)
E/AndroidRuntime(29177):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
E/AndroidRuntime(29177):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8819)
E/AndroidRuntime(29177):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:603)
E/AndroidRuntime(29177):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(29177):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(29177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(29177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(29177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(29177):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)    
E/AndroidRuntime(29177):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(29177):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm still a beginner with programming in Android, and I would like to manage properly the behavior of the button, and the media player, to simulate the operation of a piano keyboard.
I hope some of your advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `getBaseContext()` to create the `MediaPlayer` objects, use `getApplicationContext()` or `this`, depending on how persistent it needs to be. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1027438/752320) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For an application like this, you do not want to use `MediaPlayer` to do all that work.  `SoundPool` was designed for projects like this that need short sound effects.  Running this many `MediaPlayer`instances will be very slow.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html