# How to call another activity(class) from one activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using dialog box. 
I want that if i click the button, the other activity gets called. But its giving the following error.
   //The constructor Intent(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}, Class) is undefined

Here's the code

```
  builder1.setNegativeButton("secondact", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i=new Intent(this, FbsampleActivity.class)

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FbsampleActivity.class)
```

In your case, "this" refers to the DialogInterface class. You need the context of your Activity.

Answer (score 5):

start as:

```
builder1.setNegativeButton("secondact", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i=new Intent(Current_Activity.this, FbsampleActivity.class);
                    //or

                    //Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FbsampleActivity.class);
                     startactivity(i);
                }
            });
```

**NOTE:**  Do not use `getBaseContext()` use `getApplicationContext()` or Current_Activity.this`enter code here` for Starting new Activity

Comment: Could you explain why not to use getBaseContext();

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context and this google official blog http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: it' maybe cause memory leaks because it content old reference of Context if you are not updating it

Comment: Hmm I see. I've used this, and never faced any issues. But thanks for the info :) everyday you learn something new.

Comment: and +1 for your useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `this`, the class used in the `Intent i=new Intent(this, FbsampleActivity.class)` is `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` class.
You need to write `YourOuterClass.this` (the outer class). 
Try this:

```
 builder1.setNegativeButton("secondact", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Intent i=new Intent(YourActivity.this, FbsampleActivity.class)
          startActivity(i);
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
builder1.setNegativeButton("secondact", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i=new Intent(YourActivityName.this,FbsampleActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line below **intent**.. in your code..

```
 startactivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

create statically like this..

```
Intent i=new Intent(YourActivityName.this,ToWhichActivityYouWantToGo.class);
startActivity(i);
```