# context parameter for custom adapter - getApplicationContext() fails but 'this' works

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter, android-context

I have simple code snippet to implement custom list view.

In this code, I have `CustomAdapter` class which extends `ArrayAdapter`:

```
 CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);
```

The constructor of `CustomAdapter` is as below:

```
 public CustomerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, weather[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        mlayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
       mcontext = context;
        mdata = data;
    }
```

If I write this, the logcat shows following error:

```
Java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application context can not be cast to android.app.Activity
```

So I changed `getApplicationContext()` to `this`. and it worked fine:

```
 CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomerAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);
```

So, my question is : **1.** why we can't pass Application context here? (for the customadapter). and

**2.** Which are the scenarios in which we must have to pass Activity context instead of Application context?

[Note: I have already read some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141369/difference-between-getapplicationcontext-and-classname-this) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608709/android-difference-between-context), but they do not concern with specific issue here. All are saying that 'you can use any of them', but in specific situation like this, it does not work. So, please do not mark as duplicate.]

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context/7298955#7298955

Comment: @codeMagic thanks, but can you answer my first question: why "can't" we pass Application context here? ..I couldn't find anything helpful in that answer specific related to customadapter.

Comment: If I could have, I would have. I don't have a technical reason as to *why* unless you try casting it to `Activity` somewhere. But it's not the context you want. You really rarely need Application Context, imo

Comment: And, no, that answer doesn't say anything specific to `Adapter`s but it is worth reading and the links it includes. It may take a few times reading it but it will help you understand a little about why and when to use each.

Comment: My guess is you have inherited from class Application and have your own custom Application subclass correct?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the context of your activity while creating an adapter object. Application context is different from the activity context and they should never be interchanged. Using application context gives you the entire context for the application which depends on how you have set up your Application subclass is set up. While it can still compile, it may produce results that you do not expect. The reason for your crash is because of what has gone into your Application subclass and is likely specific to your case.

Simply put, adapter objects should use the local Activity context as this is the one that it is bound to.

Comment: before, i tried to use getApplicationContext() in one of my adapter and the switch in the adapter looked like the switch of the samsung tab that i am using. even the background color of the layour changed.

Answer (score 1):

Adapters should never get the `Application` context during initialization.  As the link codeMagic mentioned, you should always pass along the `Activity` to a class object if it directly relates to the life of the `Activity`...of which adapters do.

Now, it's certainly possible to give the `ArrayAdapter` an application context. It won't crash or throw an error.  However what it will do is render your views differently then expected.  Mainly because the application context lacks the theming you may or may not have supplied for your App and/or specifically for a given activity.

As to why the crash occurs? Somethings specifically wrong with your code. My guess, you are defining `mcontext` as an `Activity` so its crashing in the custom constructor...or It's defined as a `Context` but being used somewhere that as an Activity context which is causing the crash.