# Android: Customized adapter doesn't call getView method

Tags: java, android, adapter

I am Android newbie,I have check that the `getCount()` method return the value greater than 0, but both `getView()` and `getItem()` methods do not get executed.

Here is my adapter class

```
package com.zmlogisncs.fragment;

import java.util.List;

import com.zmlogisncs.dreamove.R;
import com.zmlogisncs.vo.AppointMent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class AppointAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<AppointMent> mList;

public AppointAdapter(Context context,List<AppointMent> list){
    mContext=context;
    mList=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    Log.d("ssss",mList.size()+"");
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return mList.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int poistion, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (converView==null) {
    converView=LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.appoitmentlistview_item, null);
    }
    Log.d("ssss", "ssss");
    return converView;
}

}
```

and here is my fragment class

```
public class AppoitmentPeople extends  ListFragment  {
    private View view;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         getAppoitment(getActivity());
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.appoitment_people, container, false);
        return view;
    }
public void  getAppoitment(Context mContext){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("access_token", URLManager.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    params.put("start_page", 0+"");
    params.put("type", "2");
    client.post(URLManager.GET_SELLERLIST, params,
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String content) {
                    try {
                    Response<List<AppointMent>> result=JsonUtil.deserialize(content, new TypeReference<Response<List<AppointMent>>>() {
                    });
                    List<AppointMent> list=result.getData();
                    AppointAdapter  adapter=new AppointAdapter(getActivity(),list);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("AppPeople", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            });

}
```

}

Comment: are you getting any errors?
and try with 
[this.setListAdapter(adapter);]

Comment: Are you sure that getCount is getting called?

Comment: your constructor of adapter is of Context and List but you are calling it with getActivity(); instead use getApplicationContext();

Comment: @ShvetChakra sorry, the getApplicationContext() method is not found

Comment: @Nanoc Yes, the size returns 3

Comment: You can get the context using  getActivity().getApplicationContext();

Comment: @ShvetChakra you shouldn't use applicationContext with Adapter. Read [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25924267/1276636)

Comment: thanx but i suggested that because of his constructor in custom adapter, i always use activity if @Mix is willing to pass the activity then he should modify the constructor accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}
```

change the above to

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return mList.indexOf(arg0);
}
```

Comment: Still using Eclipse, eh? :P

Comment: @Manojkumar sorry it doesn't work but eclipse works well