# Can't use getResources() within CursorAdapter subclass

Tags: android, resources, android-resources

please why is my Eclipse writing error with `getResources()` ?? 
It is writing: `The method getResources() is undefined for the type PredmetCursorAdapter`

What is wrong with it ?? On all lines with this metode i have that error, but in other classes is all okay

```
public class PredmetCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public PredmetCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView textViewUlohaName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nazovPredmetu);
    textViewUlohaName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nazov")));

    String den;
    int dlzka = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dlzka")));

    switch (dlzka)  
    {
        case 0:
            den = getResources().getString(R.string.pondelok);
            break;
        case 1:
            den = getResources().getString(R.string.utorok);
            break;
        case 2:
            den = getResources().getString(R.string.streda);
            break;
        case 3:
            den = getResources().getString(R.string.stvrtok);
            break;
        case 4:
            den = getResources().getString(R.string.piatok);
            break;
    }

    TextView textViewUlohaDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.denPredmetu);
    textViewUlohaDate.setText(den);

    // upravit hodnotu podla [od - do]
    TextView textViewUlohaTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.casPredmetu);
    textViewUlohaTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("hodina")));

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.predmet_simple_list_item, parent,
            false);

    return retView;
}

public void dni ()
{

}
}
```

Comment: try `context.getResources().getString(R.string.pondelok);` instead

Comment: Have a look at the use of Context [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context/13945633#13945633).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Use `context.getResources()` do like that remaining all `case`

```
    case 0:
        den = context.getResources().getString(R.string.pondelok);
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to access `resources` using `Context` in your `PredmetCursorAdapter` like below:

```
 switch (dlzka)  
{
    case 0:
        den = context.getResources().getString(R.string.pondelok);
        break;
    case 1:
        den = context.getResources().getString(R.string.utorok);
        break;
    case 2:
        den = context.getResources().getString(R.string.streda);
        break;
    case 3:
        den = context.getResources().getString(R.string.stvrtok);
        break;
    case 4:
        den = context.getResources().getString(R.string.piatok);
        break;
}
```

For more information go to this nice SO [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context/13945633#13945633).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get resource from activity then you can call

```
getResource()
```

directly. But if you are trying to use getResource() from any class then you can call this on the object of Context, which you can pass from activity to class where you want to call getResource().

Like if Context is mContext then use

```
mContext.getResource().
```

Answer (score 0):

Context is necessary  to add before getResources() because context informs with which activity's reference you want to get Resources .

same is used in many case even when we `inflate()` a layout , we need to pass reference. 
`context.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`

so you should use: `context.getResources()`