# Toast not showing - Android

Tags: android, toast

I've tried so many ways to show the Toast I want (on the DrawView Class) that I really don't know where to run anymore.

Apparently this is really simple, but I'm missing something. I've seen other related posts but had no success.

Any ideas please?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(drawView);

    }

}
```

DrawView Class:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class DrawView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(MyActivity myActivity) {
        super(myActivity);

        setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawText("I'm text in a canvas!", 10, 10, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"I'm a Toast!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/android-whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context/13945633#13945633).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class DrawView extends View  {

Paint paint = new Paint();
private Context context;

public DrawView(MainActivity context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawText("I'm text in a canvas!", 10, 10, paint);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm a Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    return false;

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as follows..

```
Context _context;
public DrawView(MyActivity myActivity,Context context) {
        super(myActivity);

        _context=context;
        setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    }
```

and show `Toast` using `_context`

```
Toast.makeText(_context,"I'm a Toast!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Pass the current `Context` also as an argument to the class..

Answer (score 1):

The Toast not apper is not the context reference issue its is with you on touch event problem. You Should change your **DrawView class** like this

```
public class DrawView extends View  {

Paint paint = new Paint();
Context _MyActivity;

public DrawView(Context myActivity) {
    super(myActivity);
    this._MyActivity = myActivity;
    setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawText("I'm text in a canvas!", 10, 10, paint);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // do something
        Toast.makeText(_MyActivity, "I'm a Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // do something
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       //do something
        break;
}
return true;
}



}
```

and your Your **activity class** like this

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

DrawView drawView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(drawView);
        drawView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}



@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

You dont want implement OnTouchListener in DrawView.class

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your code from:

`Toast.makeText(getContext(),"I'm a Toast!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

to:

`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I'm a Toast!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: It gives me an error: "Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext()'"

Comment: This isn't an appropriate use of GetApplicationContext(). http://stackoverflow.com/a/7298955/72357

Comment: you can try <code>  Toast.makeText('your activity'.this,"I'm a Toast!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  </code>

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the Activity use that as your context.