# NullPointerException on getBaseContext()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-context

I have a `MainActivity` class that has a method called: `updateTabTitles()`;

`updateTabTitles()` does what it sounds like, updates the titles of my tabs.

```
    String tabName = tabNames[tabNumber];
    String font = "helveticaneuebold.ttf"; // Fonts found in assets/fonts/ folder

    SpannableString title = new SpannableString(tabName);
    SpannableString subTitle;

    // This line gives me trouble
    title.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(getBaseContext(), font), 0, title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I call this function from my `ChecklistTab` class that extends the `Fragment` class. The following method is in my `ChecklistTab` class:

```
 public int calculateRemaining(ArrayList<ChecklistItem> checklistItems, int tabNumber) {
    int remaining = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < checklistItems.size(); i++) {
        if (!checklistItems.get(i).getCheckBox().isChecked() && checklistItems.get(i).getCheckBox().isEnabled() && !checklistItems.get(i).getCheckBox().getText().equals("N/A")) {
            remaining++;
        }
    }

    // NULL POINTER HERE
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).updateTabTitles(tabNumber, remaining);

    return remaining;
}
```

Lastly, I found a custom `TypefaceSpan` class online for changing fonts. This is the constructor that is called from `updateTabTitles()`

```
public TypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) {
    mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

    if (mTypeface == null) {
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext()
                .getAssets(), String.format("fonts/%s", typefaceName));

        // Cache the loaded Typeface
        sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
    }
}
```

I really don't know much about contexts, but this code used to work with my old implementation. However, since refactoring, I can't seem to figure out what's wrong now.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.brettrosen.atls.fragments.ChecklistTab.calculateRemaining(ChecklistTab.java:179)
            at com.brettrosen.atls.onclicklisteners.CheckboxOnClickListener.onClick(CheckboxOnClickListener.java:46)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4192)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17327)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your Java stack trace. Also, where are you calling `calculateRemaining()`?

Comment: Why don't you use just "this" as a context instead of getBaseContext?

Comment: @CommonsWare I posted my stacktrace. `calculateRemaining` is called from a number of different classes. Some of which are custom OnClickListener classes

Comment: `TypefaceSpan.java:22` is??

Comment: @nullpointer In the block of code above, I wrote a comment above the line saying thats where the error is thrown

Comment: "I've tried using getApplicationContext(), this, MainActivity.this, none have worked" -- well, you will be getting different stack traces for the latter two. Your problem is that `getBaseContext()` is returning `null`, and it is not possible for `this` to be `null`. I never use `getBaseContext()`, and pretty much every use I have ever seen of it online is wrong. I suggest that you switch to `this`, and post the stack trace for that crash.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context should be a good read

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated the new stacktrace and commented where the null pointer is

Comment: Well, the only way that line can directly have a `NullPointerException` is if `getActivity()` is `null`. And the only way that would happen is if your app is seriously messed up, where you have a `CompoundButton`, that you think is managed by a fragment, still on the screen after the fragment has been detached from its original activity.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `getApplicationContext` instead of `getBaseContext`

```
title.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(getApplicationContext(), font), 0, title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried using getApplicationContext(), this, MainActivity.this, none have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
title.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, font), 0, title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried using getApplicationContext(), this, MainActivity.this, none have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace says `PrearrivalPlan` is your fragment since its `onCreateView()` is being invoked. But you're calling `getActivity()` in `ChecklistTab` which seems to be another fragment and it's not attached to any activity. `getActivity()` returns null and hence the different NPEs you are seeing.

You can pass in a `Context` as an argument to those methods that need one, and use `getActivity()` in fragments only between `onAttach()` and `onDetach()` lifecycle events in the fragment lifecycle.

Comment: I think that's exactly the problem, thanks for pinpointing that. How can I use context as a parameter to use this same line `((MainActivity) getActivity()).updateTabTitles(tabNumber, remaining);` I cant seem to call `context.getActivity()`