# How do I call the context correctly to start an Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-context

Since I experienced crashes of this genre:

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires
>   the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

I started wondering of the right usage of the context for a startActivity-Intent.

This was my Kotlin-Code (Activity -> Activity):

```
btn_scan.setOnClickListener {
            val mIntent = Intent(applicationContext, Scanner::class.java)
            mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            applicationContext.startActivity(mIntent)    

        }
```

which I was able to fix with "this":

```
btn_scan.setOnClickListener {
            val mIntent = Intent(this, Scanner::class.java)
            mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            this.startActivity(mIntent)    

        }
```

But now I'm a little bit insecure of the right usage of this, since accessing it from a inner-function for example needs this@ActivityName.
So I'd like to ask you politely to explain me how to know which is the right context, when starting an Activity from an Activity, from a Fragment or from a function or using CoroutineScope

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between the various methods to get a Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026973/whats-the-difference-between-the-various-methods-to-get-a-context)

Comment: Partially, still the this and the this@Activity isn't 100% clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I can answer all your questions but here's my two cents:

Your code looked like this when your app crashed:

```
btn_scan.setOnClickListener {
            val mIntent = Intent(applicationContext, Scanner::class.java)
            mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            applicationContext.startActivity(mIntent)    
}
```

The error message said you should use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when starting an `Activity` from outside of an `Activity` context. You used the `Application` context which is like a "cousin" of the `Activity` context inheritance-wise (see [ContextWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) for subclasses and their relations), so the `Intent` flags were checked and the required flag was missing.

But why can the flag be missing if you set it explicitly?

```
mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

That's because you assign another value to *mIntent.flags* immediately after this:

```
mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

If you want to have both flags you have to *add* them:

```
mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK + Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

Now the app no longer crashes.

But is the `Application` context even necessary here? Your code is part of an `Activity` after all, and `Activity` is an indirect subclass of `Context`.

You possibly tried the following and it worked:

```
btn_scan.setOnClickListener {// Note: your IDE tells you "it: View!"
            val mIntent = Intent(applicationContext, Scanner::class.java)
            mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            this.startActivity(mIntent)    
}
```

Because inside the `OnClickListener` lambda, the `View` is referred to by "it", there is no ambiguity: "this" refers to the `Activity`, no crash.
(Of course now you could skip the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`)

Things look differently when you have something like this:

```
  with(btn_scan){ // this: Button!
        setOnClickListener{ // it: View!
            val mIntent = Intent(applicationContext, Scanner::class.java)
            mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK + Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            this.startActivity(mIntent)
        }
    }
```

Now your IDE won't accept `this.startActivity(mIntent)`. This is because here "this" refers to the `Button`. If you want another, "outer this", you have to say explicitly which one. In Kotlin, you do so by adding @ActivityName.

I suppose the same goes for coroutine code inside an `Activity` (although I must confess I'm not yet a coroutine expert): whenever the `Activity` "this" is hidden behind some local "this", you need the annotation.

Back to familiar ground: the `context` property of a `Fragment` is the `Activity`'s context if the `Fragment` is attached to an `Activity`, else it is `null`. So if it's not `null` you can use it for starting an `Activity`.

But you can even use the `Button`'s `context` property, since it is identical to the `Activity` context as well:

```
with(btn_scan){ // this: Button!
        setOnClickListener{
            val mIntent = Intent(applicationContext, Scanner::class.java)
            mIntent.flags =  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            this.context.startActivity(mIntent)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You explained perfectly the Flag problem. One question to that. So for the CLEAR_TOP I was accessing the applicationContext of the new activity already, that's why it caused the crash, right?

Comment: Well that aren't just 2 cents, that's what I was looking for! For now, I solved it with val mIntent= Intent(this,Scanner::class.java) ... and this.startActivity(mIntent) and it seems to work everywhere.

Comment: @Los Kayos - thanks for letting me know :) About "for the CLEAR_TOP I was accessing the applicationContext of the new activity"  - AFAIK any app component can only ever access its own application context (directly as a property or indirectly depends on the type of component)

Comment: as I've seen on the commis below: what's better to use "Intent.FLAG_... + Intent.FLAG_" or "Intent.FLAG or Intent.FLAG_.."?

Comment: and one last question, from what I've understood (and lease correct my now or never), it is ok to use "this" for Intent(this,Scanner::class.java) and also this.startActivity for a simple onClickListener without any other local "this" around. Right?

Comment: @Los Kayos - "yes" in Kotlin because inside of the lambda expression the View will be "it". When in doubt in any situation, you could use the debugger to get more information on what's hiding behind "this"

Comment: ' what's better to use "Intent.FLAG_... + Intent.FLAG_" or "Intent.FLAG or Intent.FLAG_.."' - I like "+" better in this case, it's closer to "and" , so it's similar to what I would say in English

Comment: Once more about the "this": my comment is valid if the OnClickListener is part of the code of an Activity, in a Fragment you have to write this.context when a Context is required

Answer (score 0):

if use kotlin

```
    btn_scan.setOnClickListener {
            val mIntent = Intent(this, Scanner::class.java)
            mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            this.startActivity(mIntent)    
}
```